# Ignore SSLHandshakeException only for one particular Server

Tags: java, security, ssl, x509certificate, pki

I need to ignore the PKIX path building exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExc
ption: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I know how to do this by writing my own class implementing `X509TrustManager` where I always `return true` from `isServerTrusted`.

But this is rather broad. My code is going to be a part of bigger project. I don't want everything else to be affected by my replacement of the trust manager.

I am always going to connect to a fixed domain name i.e. "www.myws.com". I want to only ignore the `SSLHandshakeException` only for connections to "www.myws.com".

Is something like this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing X509TrustManager - passing on part of the verification to existing verifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005318/implementing-x509trustmanager-passing-on-part-of-the-verification-to-existing)

Comment: This is *very* similar to your other question, but seems to focus more on how to set the trust manager for a particular connection. Which libraries are you using?

Comment: @Bruno It's similar to my other question. But surely not a duplicate. Approaching the same problem from 2 diff angles. SSL exception is thrown when the domain name doesn't match Subject in Cert. Here I am trying to filter based on Domain Name, there I am trying to filter based on Subject. There is little chance that the answers to 2 questions is going to be the same because I don't think the TrustMananger gets the domain name of the server at all. I would think the domain name comparison would happen before (or after) the TrustManager is asked to verify if the Cert is signed by a trusted CA.

Comment: Fair enough. It's virtually impossible to answer your question without more details about how much control you have over that client code and which libraries are in use.

Comment: To clarify, you can't 'ignore SSLHandshakeException'. It is fatal to the connection. But you can prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 1):

> There is little chance that the answers to 2 questions is going to be the same because I don't think the TrustMananger gets the domain name of the server at all.

Actually, the trust manager can get the name of the host name you were after. It depends on a number of factors though.

- Let's just assume your clients are running on Java 7.

  If you follow the same method as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19005844/372643) but use an `X509ExtendedTrustManager` (introduced in Java 7, as opposed to a plain `X509TrustManager`), you'll get additional overloaded methods that give you the current `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` as well.

  The `SSLContext` makes use of these methods when initialised with an `X509ExtendedTrustManager` instance, but not when it's a plain `X509TrustManager`, so it must be checking the type before making those calls (see quick test at the end of this answer, base on [the code in that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19005844/372643)).

  I'm not sure where this behaviour is specified the API. There doesn't seem to be anything about this `X509ExtendedTrustManager` type-check in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509ExtendedTrustManager).
  One way of making sure the extended methods are used would be to set an [enpoint identification algorithm (like HTTPS) in your `SSLParameters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html#setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm%28java.lang.String%29), but you'd need some degree of control of the client code and the libraries it uses. (This is also a feature introduced in Java 7.)

  From the `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` obtained there, you can get the `SSLSession` and the peer host, so you could perform checks there. (Note that the host name may not quite match what was intended if the library creating the `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` didn't use one of the method that passes that name as a `String`, but passed an `InetAddress` instead. You'll also lose SNI in this case.)

  You could then use such a trust manager in your default `SSLContext` (with `setDefault(...)`).
- If you don't want to affect the default `SSLContext` (a sensible choice for these kind of tweaking), you'll need to figure out how your client library can use a different one per connection. This depends entirely on what's used.

  For a traditional `URLConnection`, cast it as an `HttpsURLConnection` and set is `SSLSocketFactory` as one build from your custom `SSLContext`.

---

Which methods are used will depend on whether you've instantiated an `X509ExtendedTrustManager` or a `X509TrustManager`:

```
X509TrustManager customTm = new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return finalTm.getAcceptedIssuers();
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
        System.out
                .println("Current method: checkServerTrusted(chain, authType)");
        finalTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    //@Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
        System.out
                .println("Current method: checkServerTrusted(chain, authType, socket)");
        finalTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType, socket);
    }

    //@Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType, SSLEngine engine)
            throws CertificateException {
        System.out
                .println("Current method: checkServerTrusted(chain, authType, engine)");
        finalTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType, engine);
    }

    // Same for client-related methods.
};
```